# Volley's JsonObjectRequest gives "org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" exception

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

### Expected JSON to be send to server

```
{"syncsts":
          [
          {"status":"1","Id":"9"},
          {"status":"1","Id":"8"}
          ]
}
```

### Expected way of retrieval of JSON Object on the server

```
$arr = $_POST['syncsts']
```

**(I think )**

$arr should have [{"status":"1","Id":"9"},{"status":"1","Id":"8"}]

### Volley JsonObjectRequest Function along with JSON style parameter

```
public void updateMySQLSyncSts(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lt){
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(lt);
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
    try {
        js.put("syncsts",arr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("MainActivity",js.toString());
    String url = "http://10.0.3.2/insight/mysqlsqlitesync/updatesyncsts.php";
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, js,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MySQL DB has been informed about Sync activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("MainActivity",error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

### PHP script

```
/**
* Updates Sync status of Users
*/
include_once './db_functions.php';
//Create Object for DB_Functions clas
$db = new DB_Functions(); 
//Get JSON posted by Android Application
$json = $_POST["syncsts"];
//Remove Slashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$json = stripslashes($json);
}
//Decode JSON into an Array
$data = json_decode($json);
//Util arrays to create response JSON
$a=array();
$b=array();
//Loop through an Array and insert data read from JSON into MySQL DB
for($i=0; $i<count($data) ; $i++)
{
//Store User into MySQL DB
$res = $db->updateSyncSts($data[$i]->Id,$data[$i]->status);
//Based on inserttion, create JSON response
if($res){
    $b["id"] = $data[$i]->Id;
    $b["status"] = 'yes';
    array_push($a,$b);
}else{
    $b["id"] = $data[$i]->Id;
    $b["status"] = 'no';
    array_push($a,$b);
}
}
//Post JSON response back to Android Application
echo json_encode($a);
```

I am using the above function to send JSON formatted parameter along with my post request. when $_POST["syncsts"] line in PHP script executed the following error is thrown.

### JSONObject toString() and the Error as shown in the logcat

```
10-04 21:59:23.523 2062-2062/? I/MainActivity: {"syncsts":[{"status":"1","Id":"9"},{"status":"1","Id":"8"}]}

10-04 21:59:23.767 2062-2062/? I/MainActivity: org.json.JSONException: Value    <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

### PHP script to show what is received on server (Debugging)

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));
$arr = $_POST['syncsts'];
echo $arr;
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
echo json_encode($age);
```

### test.txt

```
{"syncsts":[{"status":"1","Id":"9"},{"status":"1","Id":"8"}]}
```

Please tell me what is wrong in the JSON format which I am trying to send to our server which was generated in Java.

Comment: so the data is sent to server. right

Comment: you can know where is the error exactly by looking at line numbers in the error messages like `at somethng.lgg.fo(FileName.java:157)` here 157 is line number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the error is at the responce from server. the  `onResponse(JSONObject response)` expects the results to be proper jsonobject. check if there is any other elements being displayed after echoing the result(such as an error message). you can check it from browser using a chrome extension called postman using which you can try sending POST and GET requests manually to server